# Keeping ViewBag value after postback

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, session, postback, viewbag

I have a problem with a ViewBag function pointer value being lost during a PostBack.

My site has a banner ( partial view ) where I indicate my customer's status by utilizing a ViewBag function pointer:

```
ViewBag.CustomerStatus= new Func<id, string>(GetCustomerStatus);
```

(Where id is my customer's id and returned string it's returned status )

As I start going to other pages that utilize the banner partial view I loose my CustomerStatus ViewBag variable. I know ViewBags are only available "per page" but how can I make my Customer status function available from other places in the application without being redundant and repeating ViewBag.CustomerStatus= new Func(GetCustomerStatus); on every single ActionMethod call ?

Is it possible to have a function pointer stored in Session/ViewState? Safe ?
How can I access my up to date customer status across postbacks ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up taking the following approach...

Instead of rendering partial view directly I changed it up so it's called through an Action method of the controller.

I created:

```
 public PartialViewResult CustomerStatus()
 {
  ...here I called my private GetCustomerStatus methods
  ViewBag.CustomerStatus = GetCustomerStatus();
  Return PartialView("
 }
```

So now instead of calling a ViewBag function pointer separately, whenever the header banner has to be rendered, instead of @Html.Partial("BannerPartialView") I call my @Html.Action(CustomerStatus) method that returns that same banner but with the customer status variable available.

Hope it's not to confusing and helps to someone else.

Answer (score 3):

There's something about this that rubs me the wrong way, architecturally speaking. You shouldn't be passing function calls to your views, you should be passing **data**. Your approach is violating the "separation of concerns" espoused by MVC.

Construct a view model that represents the data you want to display, and then fill it by calling your functions (preferably from within the model, or from the controller if you have to). Then pass the model to the view and let the view worry about how to display the data.

If you have data that is repetitive on every call, you can add it to the model by overriding OnActionExecuting method, and add the values to the model (or ViewBag) at that point.

Comment: Yeah, you're absolutely correct. ViewBag function pointers do break the whole layer separation logic but I was assigned this project that already has these ViewBag controller function pointers implemented all over the place so I went with the flow.

Anyway...The banner partial view already has a model that it's pulling the data from. I don't think I can replace it with my own new Model. I don't think there is a way to pass a secondary model to a view, is there ?

That's kind of why I though Session pointer would be the best approach. What are your thoughts ?

Comment: Then maybe your best bet is just to stuff the value coming back from the function pointer into ViewBag?